# Does importing a large object and only using a few of it's properties affect react app performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, optimization

I have a large object with more than 100 properties and it is exported from a file.
Does importing the whole object inside a component affect app performance (in production or development) ?

```
//largeObject has mutiple properties
import largeObject from '../index.js';

largeObject.a1();
```

And I don't want to do it like below ,So I can access Object properties names with auto-complete.

```
import {a1} from largeObject;
//don't wanna do it like this
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After further research I figured out, Importing a large object with more than 100 properties into a component can have performance implications, especially if the object is not used in its entirety. When you import a large object, it occupies memory, even if you only use a small part of it.

Try Destructuring the object in order to improve performance.